# How push path to proper context in React Router from outside route context?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I have some dynamically created components that are created outside the ReactRouter node/component, so ReactRouter considers them to not be inside a context and if I try to use `ReactRouter.Link` it throws the error:

```
Links rendered outside of a router context cannot handle clicks
```

I have found a work around by using this:

```
var routes = ReactDOM.render((
    <ReactRouter.Router history={ReactRouter.browserHistory}>
        <ReactRouter.Route  path="/" component={Main}>
          <ReactRouter.IndexRoute component={Homepage}/>
          <ReactRouter.Route path="about" component={About} />
        </ReactRouter.Route>
    </ReactRouter.Router>
), document.getElementById('routes'));

//So items outside routes can still use the router
routes.goTo = function(route)
{
    //Go to the route
    routes.history.push( route );
};
```

This works, but is there also a way to get/set the context and use that to navigate?